# How to see a distribution of outcomes of a while loop?

Tags: python, simulation, probability, distribution

Imagine you have a while loop that includes a random outcome so that the output of the while loop is different each time. How can you simulate the while loop many times and see the distribution of outcomes?

I know how to run the while loop but I don't know how to simulate the loop multiple times and see the outcome distribution. For example, how would I simulate the loop below 100 times and see the distribution of outcomes?

```
import random

rolls = 0
count = 0
while rolls < 10:
  dice = random.randint(1,6)
  rolls = rolls + 1

  count = count + dice

count
```

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "see the outcome". On way would be to let `count = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` before the loop, do `count[dice-1] += 1` inside the loop (instead of `count = count + dice`), and then `print(count)` after the loop.

(The `dice-1` part is because Python uses 0-based indexing. The `+= 1` thing is just shorthand, i.e., `x += 1` is the same as `x = x + 1`)

Comment: Ideally I would see a histogram. For the example I'm actually working on I'd like to simulate 100k times. I don't know how to simulate it that many times.

Comment: Here's a poor man's histogram (for after the loop, and after the changes I detail in my previous comment): Assume a fixed and reasonable number of columns in your terminal, say 80. Loop over the numbers 1 through 6, and output a number of symbols (say `#`) to the terminal such that it shows the appropriate distribution value at the given number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an empty list of `all_rolls = []` and then `.append()` each now roll to it. This will result in a list of numbers, each number being the result of that roll (so `all_rolls[0]` would be the first roll).

Then use `matplotlib` to make your histogram.

I would also avoid the `while` loop since you are just incrementing, which is what a for loop over a range is for. I do the for loop with `_` instead of using something like `i` since we don't actually use the value from the range, we just want to do it 10 times.

```py
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

all_rolls = []
for _ in range(10):
    this_roll = random.randint(1, 6)
    all_rolls.append(this_roll)

plt.hist(all_rolls)
plt.show()
```

If you want to run the above 100 times and plot the sums of the rolls for each, then you can wrap that loop in a function and then return the sum of the list, and do that 100 times.

```py
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def my_loop():
    all_rolls = []
    for _ in range(10):
        this_roll = random.randint(1, 6)
        all_rolls.append(this_roll)
    return sum(all_rolls)


all_roll_sums = []
for _ in range(100):
    all_roll_sums.append(my_loop())

plt.hist(all_roll_sums)
plt.show()
```